# easyocr throws ValueError: Invalid input type. Supporting format = string(file path or url), bytes, numpy array

Tags: python, path, working-directory, easyocr

[image: 1]

after including all necessary libraries and doing following steps :

```
image_path=r'uptosomething.jpg'    
img=cv2.imread(image_path)     
reader=easyocr.Reader(['en'],gpu=False) 
text=reader.readtext(img)
```

i am getting this error can someone please help me.

as i am doing it in colab ...
1)so i have tried uploaded the image and take link of path from there .
2)then making it raw image using image_path=r'uptosomething.jpg'

but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `img is None`, isn't it? `print(os.getcwd())` please

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: @anu 
you have to `import numpy as np` and use it as `reader.readtext(np.array(img))`

Comment: @iambdot no, that must not be done. `img`, coming from `cv2.imread`, is a numpy array **already** (or None). if it is an array, applying `np.array()` is superfluous. if it's None, that means the file path was wrong or the file was broken. in either case, your advice does not fix the issue and may even hide issues that should be noticed.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly put the file_path in **reader.readtext()**.

```
image_path=r'uptosomething.jpg'        
reader=easyocr.Reader(['en'],gpu=False) 
text=reader.readtext(image_path)
```

Hope this works.